# onblur not working but onclick is

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I'm trying to use onblur to make a home button appear when a particular link is scrolled away from.
This is the code in the body.

```
<div id="lynx">
      <a href="#resume" onblur="btnDisplay()"><h3>Resume</h3></a>
      <a href="#projects"><h3>Projects</h3></a>
      <a href="#connect"><h3>Connect</h3></a>
 </div>
```

This is the function, which works when called via onclick.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function btnDisplay() {
            document.getElementById("homeBtn").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Is there some trick to using onblur that I'm not getting?

Comment: onblur is when you leave a field, which has been focused before

Comment: The `blur` event happens when an element loses focus, not when it's _scrolled away from_.

Comment: [onblur Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

Comment: Sounds like you want [onmouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseout)

Answer (score 3):

The event you are looking for is probably `onmouseup`. Onblur is available on text boxes. When you deselect them the blur function is called.

For anchor tags, you can use click, mousedown, or mouseup.

If you want something to happen when the window is scrolled away, you have to track the onscroll event, which is available on the `window` object.

Here is a naive implementation:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
   var position = window.scrollY;
   if (position > positionofObject){
       // do work.
   }
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, except I want to check if positionofObject is _less_ than position. Thanks!

Comment: oops, I just fixed it.